# using mod_rewrite to change pages with a colon

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

By checking my error logs, I found that i have a link to `http://site.com/javascript:;;`

I want to use a mod_rewrite rule to redirect the user to the homepage.
I tried all of the following:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /javascript: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /javascript%3a [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /javascript\%3a [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /javascript%%3a [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /javascript: [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /javascript%3a [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /javascript\%3a [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /javascript%%3a [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=301]
```

But none of these conditions catch the colon.

Thanks

Comment: @tmg - just tried it, doesn't work. according to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html, its only for output

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I don't see the point in this really. This is either some strange hacking attempt, or more likely, a broken link somewhere on your, or somebody else's, page. I would strive to locate and fix that link instead.

Comment: I already changed the bad link, but I hate leaving things like this. I want to know how to treat colons! :D

Comment: @yoav fair enough. Strange, your rules should work. Maybe redirect to an external site and add `%{REQUEST_URI}` as a GET parameter? That should show you what the URI looks like internally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the `RewriteCond`. You can simplify this like so:

`RewriteRule javascript:;; http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [NC,L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

OK, i'm sorry. it seems that my local server has some misconfigurations.
on my production server, this works:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /javascript:;; [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=301]
```

pppfffff. took me some time. :)